# Library that produces an image of an audio file's waveform

Tags: library, audio, c#

I'm looking for a library that can give me an image (think *.png*) from an audio file with configurable height and width. Waveform image is something like this:

[image]

I'm planning on using it in my C# app. The audio file may be in various formats like *mp3*, *flac* and *ogg*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in python as detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625085/how-to-plot-a-wav-file).  The python could be used offline or you can embed python within programs written in other languages.

Comment: From what I understand, the linked question has answers describing how to make a custom waveform drawing method in python and using its mathematical plot drawing libraries. This seems like a lot of unnecessary steps.

Comment: 12 Lines of code doesn't seem a lot of work to me!

Comment: It's not about work, it's about quality and reliability. I don't know what I'll get using that. Probably exceptions. And besides it's a lot more work if you want to use Python libs in a C# app.

Answer (score 1):

[NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/) is a free (MS Public License) library for audio processing in C#.

The [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/ZnFoVuOVrUQ?t=130) shows how to add controls to Visual Studio for audio visualization.

This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19265793/480982) shows some code that reads an MP3 file with NAudio and paints a PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

[audiowaveform](https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform) is a C++ command-line application that generates waveform data from either MP3, WAV, FLAC, Ogg Vorbis, or Opus format audio files.

[image]

It specifically supports PNG output

See the [CLI options](https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform#usage) for more information.